# How exactly does the auto brightness work in macOS?

Tags: mac, imac

If I have auto brightness on, I noticed that if I manually adjusted the brightness, it will never go back to auto again.

Does it go back to auto again, only under certain conditions?

Only after a certain period of time?

And does it have an "internal" value that it goes to for a given ambient light level?

Or does it "auto" adjust based on the value you set and use that as a baseline?

Answer (score 1):

There's no documentation on this, so the following is based on observation:

In auto mode, data from the ambient light sensor is used to automatically brighten or dim the display brightness. In manual mode, the ambient light sensor data isn't used; default display brightness is as you set manually.

When set to auto but you adjust the brightness manually, it stays at that level until you change it. However, auto mode is still on, so if the sensor detects a change in the illumination level, it adjusts the brightness (e.g. if you cover the sensor, the screen becomes darker. If you shine a light on the sensor, the screen becomes brighter). When the illumination level returns to normal, the brightness returns to what you had set manually.